# Proof of theorem $20.5$ Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

First the metric on $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ is defined as $$D(x,y)=sup\left\{ {\bar d(x_i,y_i)}\over i \right\}$$  where $\bar d(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),1\}$  and $\bar d$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb R$.

$V$ is the basis element for the product topology on $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ Then $V$ has the form 
$$V=(x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon)\times (x_2-\epsilon,x_2+\epsilon)\times ....(x_N-\epsilon,x_N+\epsilon)\times \mathbb R \times \mathbb  R\times ...........$$ where $N$ is chosen large enough such that $1/N \lt \epsilon$

Then given any $y\in \mathbb R^{\omega}$,
$${{\bar d(x_i,y_i)}\over i}\le {1\over N}$$ for $i\ge N$.

Untill this point its clear . My problem is the next step  that says
$$D(x,y)\le \max \left\{{{\bar d(x_1,y_1)}\over {1}} , {{\bar d(x_2,y_2)}\over 2},....,{{\bar d(x_N,y_N)}\over N},{1\over N} \right\}$$ for I think it should be 
$$D(x,y)\ge \max \left\{{{\bar d(x_1,y_1)}\over {1}} , {{\bar d(x_2,y_2)}\over 2},....,{{\bar d(x_N,y_N)}\over N},{1\over N} \right\}$$ as $D(x,y)$ is the $supremum$ , how can it be less than the $\max$  at all  $?$

Please help clear my doubt . Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, your book is correct :

As $D(x,y) = \sup \left\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_i,y_i)}{i}, i \in \Bbb N^* \right\}$, you have that

$$D(x,y) = \max \left\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_1,y_1)}{1}, \cdots ,\frac{\bar{d}(x_N,y_N)}{N} , \sup \left\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_i,y_i)}{i} , i >N \right\} \right\}$$

then you use the hypothesis that
$$\sup \left\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_i,y_i)}{i} , i >N \right\} \leq  \frac{1}{N}$$
to get

$$D(x,y) \leq \max \left\{ \frac{\bar{d}(x_1,y_1)}{1}, \cdots ,\frac{\bar{d}(x_N,y_N)}{N} , \frac{1}{N} \right\}$$